# How to archive enterprise app with Xcode6?

Tags: ios, xcode6, enterprise

Packed with Xcode6 enterprise APP need to enter the enterprise developer account?
I can pack app with Xcode5,but in Xcode6 it seems some different,I have  right provisioning profile and xxx.p12,

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 6 you need to be a team member of the particular Developer Program account and you need to have the rights to make a distribution build. This means you need to be a team agent.

For more info [see this](http://www.thecave.com/2014/09/16/using-xcodebuild-to-export-a-ipa-from-an-archive/).

Hope this helps.. :)